# Http client instances per target host

Tags: go, microservices, httpclient

Assuming, a web go application has to HTTP calls to 3 micro-services with different paths using the HTTP client library.
Is it best practice to create 3 instances of HTTP clients? So I assume by doing this each HTTP client instance will keep the connections so it won't establish new connections or reuse the TCP handshake?.

```
// Multi http client instances
cl1 := http.Client{}
cl2 := http.Client{}
cl3 := http.Client{}

c1, _ := cl1.Get(foo_url)
c1a, _ := cl1.Get(foo_url + "/bar")
c1b, _ := cl1.Get(foo_url + "/baz")
c2, _ := cl2.Get(bar_url)
c2a, _ := cl2.Get(bar_url + "/foo")
c2b, _ := cl2.Get(bar_url + "/bar")
c3, _ := cl3.Get(baz_url)

// vs single instance http client
cl := http.Client{}

c1, _ := cl.Get(foo_url)
c2, _ := cl.Get(foo_url + "/bar")
c3, _ := cl.Get(foo_url + "/baz")
c4, _ := cl.Get(bar_url)
c5, _ := cl.Get(bar_url + "/foo")
c6, _ := cl.Get(bar_url + "/bar")
c7, _ := cl.Get(baz_url)
```

Comment: You can use a single client.

Comment: single client, multiple http response is fare enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an uninitialized HTTP client, it uses the `DefaultTransport` to implement the connection management. Thus even though you have multiple clients, you have a single shared transport implementation. That implementation will manage connection pooling in a way that is satisfactory for most cases.

Comment: Assume I will clone the Transport for every HTTP client initialization, is it still recommended to create more than 1 HTTP client instance?

Comment: we can do something like this right? ```t := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).Clone()``` to create multiple instances of Transport?

Comment: Well, looks like you can clone it. My bad. However, it only copies the exported fields of it, not the whole state. That would give you a separate connection pool for each client.

Comment: that's why I'm wondering whether having different timeout & connection pools for each target host is good practice?

Comment: Is that a bottleneck? If not, I suggest don't worry about it.